# Mongodb java aggregate match with objectid type

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate values based on `group by`, `match` and `sort`. However, my matching field type is ObjectId. I have an input parameter which is a type of `ObjectId(ObjectId settingId)`, however, below code does not return anything.

Can anyone find the problem in my code?

```
   AggregateIterable < Document > iterable = thermalComfortCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
      new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$Timestamp").append("ThermalComfortList", new Document("$push", "$ThermalComfort"))),
      new Document("$match", new Document("settingID", settingId)),
      new Document("$sort", new Document("_id", 1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing a group on the first stage, print that result to check if there's a "settingID" field on the top level.
From you $group stage it seems like the output will be:

```
[
{
_id : value of $Timestamp,
ThermalComfortList : []},
...
]
```

When posisble do the $match stage before the $group stage. $match is then able to use the (i hope available) index on settingID

Comment: Do you mean I need to project settingID?

Comment: I don't know where settingID is in your document structure. is it in ThermalComfort? When not you have to project / include it in your $group stage. When possible do the match before the $group stage. mongoDB can then make use of (i hope) the available index on settingID

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BasicDBObject as follows:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("settingID", new ObjectId("")));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Timestamp").append("ThermalComfortList", new BasicDBObject("$push", "$ThermalComfort")));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1));
List<DBObject> aggregateList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
aggregateList.add(match11);
aggregateList.add(group11);
aggregateList.add(group11);
AggregationOutput result = collection.aggregate(aggregateList);
```